# Помогите решить задачку, используя PHP и JS

Tags: php, javascript, задание-на-собеседовании

На собеседовании в тесте попалась задача:

> У вас есть обычный жёсткий диск, на котором кто-то случайно записал
>   копию существующих файлов. Это привело к дублированию файлов, которое
>   вы хотели бы найти, при этом данный человек, при копировании, не
>   оставил прежние имена файлов. Опишите способ решения того, как найти
>   все дубликаты файлов (нас интересует какой файл и сколько копий
>   существуют на диске). Попробуйте придумать решение, которое бы
>   работало так быстро, как это возможно.

Не понимаю каким боком этот вопрос связан с PHP/JS. Он бы больше подходил бы к С разработчикам. 
Скорей всего здесь есть подковырка в вопросе.

Comment: Такую задачку без разницы на каком языке решать (хотя имхо насчет C вы правы), тут дело не в этом. Я думаю php тут ни при чем, вас просто хотят проверить на способность к программированию, построению алгоритмов, поиску решений.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что решение задачи за автора

Comment: Ну если пути исходников и дублей известны - то сравнить файлы по размеру... найдя дубли... а потом эти файлы что одинаковые по размеру, проверить на дубль содержимого, через какой-нибудь md5 содержимого)

Comment: Я согласен что надо закрыть вопрос. Но всё равно выскажу своё мнение просто использовать сторонюю библиотеку или программу допустим так `system('fdups -R /mnt/disc/',$result);` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes

Comment: я бы решал в два прохода: в первый скинул бы размер каждого файла (не знаю наверняка, но такой вызов не должен читать сам файл и должен быть значительно быстрее) в промежуточное хранилище (файл, бд) и отфильтровал симлинки, во второй проверял содержимое файлов, у которых совпал размер.

Comment: PHP и JS в вопросе не фигурирует. Скорее всего, в ответе предполагается просто алгоритм, а PHP и JS вы уже додумали сами исходя из того, куда попали :)

Answer (score -1):

А если так? Будет корректно?

```
function dir_get_duplicates_by_size_md5( $path )
{
dir_callback( $path , 'dir_size') {
    if( is_file( $path ) )
    {
        $md5    = md5( file_get_contents( $path ) );
        $GLOBALS['files'][$md5][]   = $path;
        $GLOBALS['filesize']    += filesize( $path );
    }
} );
$GLOBALS['files']   = array_map( function ( $e ) {
                if( count( $e ) > 1 )
                {
                    return $e;
                }
            } , $GLOBALS['files'] );
$GLOBALS['files']   = array_filter( $GLOBALS['files'] );
}
$path    = realpath( 'E:\files' );
$files   = array( );
$filesize = 0;
dir_get_duplicates_by_md5( $path );
echo $files . 'Files ' . $filesize . ' Bytes';
```

Comment: Вот я бы за globals на собеседовании точно давал бы красную карточку. Кроме того, здесь просто сама собой напрашивается вероятность переполнения памяти, при котором это всё грохнется.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что лучше использовать вместо globals? И как избежать переполнение памяти? Спасибо!